# need regular expression from 1 to 20 with 2 floating point number

Tags: c#, regex, numbers

I need some help for an regular expression for numbers between 1 and 20 with 2 floating point number in c# ?

```
examples : 5 , 6.5 , 7.75 , 10 , 12.3 , 19.99
```

far i got to this

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]?|20)[.]?0*(?:[1-9][0-9]?)?$
```

but it`s not working and its accepting more than 20 to,
so according to the comments is anybody here what is the regex that accept numbers between 1-20 that have 2 floating point number optionaly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this (upto two decimal numbers)

```
^(([1-9]|1\d)(\.\d{1,2})?|20)$
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/xV1yA0/1).

If you need exactly two decimal numbers

```
^(([1-9]|1\d)(\.\d{2})|20.00)$
```